# How to run oozie for historic dates?

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to run an oozie coordinator for historic dates such as

```
start-date = 2013-02-01T00:00Z 
end-date = 2013-03-15T00:00Z
frequency = 1 day
```

Oozie should have started/materialized all the actions for these days immediately

```
2013-02-01T00:00Z
2013-02-02T00:00Z
2013-02-03T00:00Z
2013-02-04T00:00Z
...
...
2013-03-15T00:00Z
```

But instead of that Oozie is generating/executing one action per day and I have to wait 43 days to see the results. **Is there any way I could execute these actions immediately?**

Answer (score 0):

Explicit Timeout control (-1) in the coordinator solved the problem and action gets materialized in every 5 min. **Can we configure this 5 minute interval?**

```
<controls>
    <timeout>-1</timeout>
</controls>
```

Comment: Yes, configure `oozie.service.CoordMaterializeTriggerService.lookup.interval` (in seconds) in your Oozie server's `oozie-site.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you are asking , it should be easy to do.

```
<coordinator-app name="${coordName}" frequency="${coord:endOfDays(1)}"
start="${start}" end="${end}" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
```

you can set `${start}` to the start historical date you want

Comment: As you may see in the description that I already made the workflow/coordinator correctly but getting unexpected result.Now i have solved that by adding explicit timeout value.Do you have any idea how we can configure that minimum materialization value of 5 min? Thanks.

Comment: can you add your coordinator xml file and the properties file you use to run the oozie ?

Comment: you can use `-dryrun` to see coordinator output